# Moving all windows from Monitor X to Monitor Y

Tags: windows-7, multi-monitor

I am looking for a program or script (e.g. AHK/Sikuli) that can move all windows from Monitor X to Monitor Y. I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with 6 monitors.

Comment: Six monitors Franck?  You win.  ;-)